# Converting pseudo-eigen system to eigen system

Tags: polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Consider 3x3 matrix with unknowns $v_0$,$v_1$,$v_2$:

$$A \vec{v} =A\left[\begin{array}{l}v_0\\v_1\\v_2\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{l}v_0 v_0\\v_0 v_1\\v_1v_2\end{array}\right]$$

As you can see, this is almost eigenvalue problem $A \vec{v} = v_0 \vec{v}$, except last equation. Is it possible to find some matrix $A'$, so that $A' \vec{u} = v_0 \vec{u}$, i.e. convert initial problem to the eigenvalue problem? I am of course interested in generalized solition, which could be somehow applied to n*n matrix, where few last lines are $v_i v_j$ instead of $v_0 v_j$...

Comment: For your $3 \times 3$ system, you could multiply the last row of $A$ by $\frac {v_0}{v_1}$

Comment: But this doesn't give me eigen-like problem on the left side any more.